# How can I "dump" a Function to a file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

For example, I have a function `func()`:

```
int func (int a, int b) {return a + b;}
```

Now I want write it to a file, so that I can use the system-call mmap to load it with PROT_EXEC and I can call it from another program.What should I do for it?

Comment: That is not how compiled languages work.

Comment: I just want the module can be load in Linux and Windows(VirtualAllocEx )

Comment: The algorithm is independent of platform. So I don't want to let the module compiled for 2 times

Comment: There's no toolchain that I know of that supports this, it's just asking for trouble; just for starters, the ABI and the CRT on Windows and Linux are different. Just compile the whole thing once for each platform.

Comment: Use an interpreted language to accomplish your goals. C might be to low level for what you are trying to do. Have you heard of Python, Ruby, or PHP? A lot of those languages have what one would Reflection where you can "dump" the function to a file.

Comment: @MatteoItalia but it is possible,refer to <in Chinese language,but you could read his code>http://www.hoverlees.com/blog/?p=1014

Comment: @self maybe you are true,but i prefer to use c :)

Comment: @MaGeek that seems harder than to compile the program for each platform. To learn it may be interesting, but if you just want your code to work you are better off with a simpler solution.

Comment: @MaGeek: the code extracted in that sample can be used only on the same platform (it requires the ABI to be the same); also, the saved/loaded code cannot refer to any global or call directly any external function anyway, since those references may not be valid in the new context where it's loaded (that's why it uses that function-pointers array, trying to improvise a poor man's linker/loader).

Comment: i have given up the idea.because i find out the better one.think you everyone answer the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know what signature you need and a static library or the location of a shared library at compile time, you probably just want to include the header and link against the output library. If you want to invoke a function dynamically, you probably want [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) / [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) (UNIX) or  [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) / [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) (Windows) for loading the libary dynamically and retrieving the address of the function by name.

Note that the cases where you actually need to load a library dynamically (at least explicitly) are pretty rare. This is often used for modular architectures (e.g. "plugins" or "extensions") where individual pieces of the application are distributed separately (which can be achieved more securely using IPC rather than dynamic loading... see my note below). Or for cases where your application is not allowed to include dependencies statically and needs to conditionally supply behavior based on the existence of certain library dependencies in the environment in which it happens to be executing. In most cases, though, you'll simply want to include a header that declares the symbols you need and compile for each target platform (possibly using `#if...#else` macros if there are symbols that vary across OSes or OS versions).

From a stability, security, and code complexity standpoint, I personally recommend that you avoid dynamic library loading. For core system functionality, it's reasonable to link against a dynamic library, but you'll want to do it in a way where the burden of dynamic loading is entirely on your toolchain (i.e. you shouldn't need to call dlopen or LoadLibrary explicitly). For other functionality, it is almost always better to statically link (assuming you distribute updates when there are security fixes for your dependencies), since this will avoid you getting broken by incompatible version updates and also prevent your users from experiencing dependency hell (you require version A but some other application requires version B); modular architectures are often better (and more securely) achieved through inter-process communication (IPC), since dynamically loaded libraries live in the process of the program that loads them (thereby giving them access to the entire process's virtual memory space), whereas with interprocess-communication, each component would be a separate process, and individual components would only have access to information that was given to it explicitly by the calling process, which would make it more difficult for a malicious component to steal data from the caller or other components or to produce instability.

Comment: yes, dlopen can load .so file but I want do not depend on the operating system.

Comment: PROT_EXEC and mmap are OS-specific, so it wasn't clear from your question that you were looking for something portable. However, Windows supports equivalent functionality in the form of "LoadLibrary" and "GetProcAddress".

Comment: Any approach to doing this would be much less portable than `dlopen`, and could not be easily made to work with existing compilers/toolchains because doing so involves all sorts of assumptions about ABI, executable format, how code accesses global data and function symbol addresses, etc.

Comment: do not agree with `For other functionality, it is almost always better to statically link`, besides reducing total resource consumption with dynamic linking, dynamic linking means that bug fixes and upgrades to libraries **do not need to compile the whole project completely** that's very important in a project with millions of lines of code.

Comment: You can do partial compilation with static linking too. The main difference is the user will download the exe rather than just the new dll, but that's not really that big of a deal most the time.

Comment: @jujj, I used to think so, too. However, I've seen dependency hell enough times that I no longer agree. Not to mention that dynamic loading provides a number of security and debugging challenges. It's much better to provide an auto-update functionality where you regularly integrate and deploy fixes to dependencies.

Comment: Also on reliability, shared objects load into the same process as the rest of the program. So while they are separate files, a bug in one can still crash (or be a security risk) to the other. If you do want to separate functionality into different components, I much prefer separate programs in isolated processes that communicate somehow (like through a pipe to the parent and/or some shared memory) than shared libraries. These bits can be replaced and restarted independently like dll load/unload, but also can crash independently - a big help for reliability.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe, I completely agree (that's why my recommendation was to use IPC for modular architectures rather than dynamic loading).

Comment: now i use statically linksd shared library....gcc -o libxxx.so -shared -static -static-libgcc -fPIC

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan ah, of course! I missed that bit when first reading it, but looks like we're in complete agreement.

Answer (score 2):

The sanest thing if you want this to actually be used in the real world is probably to just compile the source as part of your program on each platform, like a regular function.

Next best is probably a separate process that you talk to rather than merge with.

Semi-sane (but still not a great choice, see our discussion in the other answer) would be making the shared library, like Michael Aaron Safyan said.

But if you want to know how it works just because - say, you want to write your own dynamic linker, or are doing some kind of runtime code generation like a JIT compiler, or if you just wanna know - you can make a raw code file.

To use it, what we'd have to do is similar to what the linker does - load the code at a particular address that it is made to work on and run it. There is position independent code that can run at any address, too.

Let's first get our function compiled and linked, then output into a raw image for a certain address. Assume the function is `func` in the file `func.c` and we're using gcc on Linux. (A Windows compiler would have similar options - gcc on Windows is exactly the same, I believe, but something like Digital Mars's C compiler does it differently with the linker command being `/BINARY` for instance)

Anyway, here's what I ran:

```
gcc -c func.c # makes func.o
ld func.o --oformat=binary -e func -o func.binary
```

This generates a file called func.binary. You can disassemble it most easily with `ndisasm -b 64 func.binary` (or `-b 32` if you compiled the C in 32 bit mode) to confirm it looks right - I see an add instruction there, so looks good to me.

If you loaded that and mmaped then called it... it should work.

Problems will be quick to come up though:

- If there's more than one function in that file, they'll all be squished together.
- The addresses they try to use to call each other may be totally wrong.
- Global variables and other static data will be messed up.

And there's more. The operating system uses more complex file formats for executables and libraries for a reason!

To go to the next step, you could consider writing an ELF or PE loader which reads that metadata off a standard file. Of course, once you get into much of this, you'll be doing exactly what the OS provides with `dlopen` and `LoadLibrary`.... so unless the goal is to just learn about the guts, just call those functions and call it done!

Comment: Minor clarification: while I pointed you can use a shared library, my overall message was recommending against it.

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant by "second" sanest.. maybe I can edit to clear it up.

Comment: Although I don't think I will adopt the idea, I think after seeing your answer I learned a lot.

Comment: What's nice about trying this thing yourself is you'll start to understand why things work the way they do and can appreciate the OS design more. And once you know the OS design, then you can go back and abuse it a little :)